# mod_rewrite multiple parameters with regex (.*)

Tags: regex, .htaccess, unicode, url-rewriting

I have a url like the following:

```
http://www.example.com/cat/دسته/page/2/
```

As you can see there is Unicode string up there. I use the following directive in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^cat/(.*)/page/([0-9]*)/$ cat.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
```

The problem here is the regex engine parses the url above and it sets all the `دسته/page/2/` as the first parameter while I only want the Unicode string as my first parameter and the integer as the second.

How can that be done? Is there a better way for finding Unicode characters other than `(.*)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bit odd -- it should not behave like that -- must be Unicode messing the whole thing.

In any case -- use this instead -- it is more precise:

```
RewriteRule ^cat/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/$ cat.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
```

You can replace `[0-9]` by `\d` -- does exactly the same and is shorter.